# How to write chained dynamic object properties in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am switching a JS project to TS and am struggling with a certain part of my code, which TS complains about and I don't know how to resolve the issue.

In TS, I want to collect data in a dynamic object, called `licensesStats`, that in the end might look like this:

```
{
  'DYNAMIC_NAME': {
    'Usage count': 2,
    'Used by': {
      'SOME_DYNAMIC_NAME': null,
      'SOME_OTHER_NAME': null,
      [...]
    }
  },
  [...]
}
```

For my `licensesStats` object, I have created the following `interface`:

```
interface LicenseStatsCounter {
    [key: string]: number;
}

interface LicenseStatsModule {
    [key: string]: null;
}

interface LicenseStatsModules {
    [key: string]: LicenseStatsModule;
}

interface LicensesStats {
    [key: string]:
        | LicenseStatsCounter
        | LicenseStatsModules;
}

licensesStats: LicensesStats = {}
...
```

The keys "Usage count" and "Used by" are stored in variables, and so in the code during data collection, there is a command that says:

`licensesStats[license][titleUsedBy][moduleNameAndVersion] = null;`

But TS complains:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'number | LicenseStatsModule'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type
> 'number | LicenseStatsModule'.

What do I have to do in order to satisfying TypeScript's needs?

P.S.: Here is an example TS file for my issue:

```js
const titleUsageCount = 'Usage count';
const titleUsedBy = 'Used by';

interface LicenseStatsCounter {
    [key: string]: number;
}

interface LicenseStatsModule {
    [key: string]: null;
}

interface LicenseStatsModules {
    [key: string]: LicenseStatsModule;
}

interface LicensesStats {
    [key: string]: LicenseStatsCounter | LicenseStatsModules;
}

// Exported functions:
export const readLicenses = (argv: Argv) => {
    const licensesStats: LicensesStats = {};

    const license = 'MIT';
    const moduleNameAndVersion = 'chalk@1.0.0';
    licensesStats[license] = licensesStats[license] || {
        [titleUsageCount]: 0,
        ...((argv.summaryPlus as boolean) && { [titleUsedBy]: {} }),
    };
    (licensesStats[license][titleUsageCount] as number)++;

    // This is the problematic line, where TS says:
    // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'number | LicenseStatsModule'.
    // No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'number | LicenseStatsModule'.
    licensesStats[license][titleUsedBy][moduleNameAndVersion] = null;
    }
};
```

Comment: COuld you please provide reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current setup, typescript reaches `licensesStats[license][titleUsedBy]` and sees two possible values: either a `number` or an `object` (the LicenseStatsModule) and throws an error because a number can't contain a property.

You're going to need some kind of conditional checks to make typescript happy, something like:

```
const x = licensesStats[license][titleUsedBy];

if(typeof x !== "number"){
  const y = x[moduleNameAndVersion];

  // ... do something
  return;
}

// ... do something
return;
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I struggled with the type definitions, but in the end it was just a simple bit of conditional checking.